# What is the process for publishing academic papers?

Tags: publishing, non-fiction, magazines, academic-writing

While studying in my first term as EPIR student I had to prepare several papers. I gave those to my family and friends, to read and comment upon. I was surprised when they advised me to publish them. So here I am, thinking how to do that.

```
[politics]

Did nuclear weapons bring the world to the edge of war or did they
help ensure the peace?
https://gist.github.com/c826c3597eeccfca835b

Do you agree with the view that “democracy is the worst form of
government except all those other forms that have been tried from time
to time”?
https://gist.github.com/257ccf9db51bb22507d5

[economics]

Why did the most powerful computer in the world have an ashtray?
https://gist.github.com/21dc25762c1a66c8b35f
```

Considering the length of those articles, I would agree to trim them before publishing. I would appreciate your help and/or criticism.

Gajus Gabrielius Kuizinas

Comment: We're not here to review your work.  We're here to answer legitimate questions about writing.  You might want to rephrase the question if you're asking an actual question about publishing.

Comment: @divided - I believe @Guy is wondering what venues are available for work like this, and perhaps how one goes about submitting.  That seems valid enough to me.  Also, [Jeff's recent proclamation](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/181/policy-change-writing-critique-questions-now-welcome) states that critiques are also on-topic for this site.  However, if Guy wants critique, that should probably be a separate question for each piece of writing and should offer some guidance as to what particular aspects of the work he would like feedback on.

Comment: Thank you @divided. As for critique, I would simply like to know either a paper as such is fit for publishing [anywhere]. I to realize that providing interesting topic is something not enough and that it may be that these papers are rather to "sophisticated". But there should be magazines willing to publish them, with an appropriate auditory.

Comment: since you are a student, wouldn't a professor at your school be able to advise you on what academic journals are available to you?

Comment: At the moment I am in the university. Asking precisely that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into academic journals in your subject areas, although the authors in academic journals are often professors or graduate students.  Professors at your university should be able to tell you if you can qualify, what journals are available, what would be a good fit, and how the submission process works.  At many universities students are assigned academic adviser in their major.  Your adviser is an advocate for your academic success.  He or she should be your first resource; you want to develop a good relationship with your adviser to further your professional success as well, so start now.

One route that might work for publishing in an academic journal, if you are not currently a graduate student, is to work with a professor whose name will appear on the paper alongside yours for publication.  This will work best if your paper is in the area of interest of the professor you approach.  Your adviser or the professor who taught your class where you wrote the paper may be able to provide names.

For more information on academic publishing, check out:

- [How to publish your journal paper](http://www.apa.org/monitor/sep02/publish.aspx) from the APA monitor
- [How to publish in top journals](http://www.roie.org/how.htm) from the Review of International Economics

If you find that your work does not qualify for a peer-reviewed, academic journal, you can look into publishing in other magazines.  More information on query letters, proposals, and other steps you might want to take can be found [here](http://freelancewrite.about.com/od/getpublished/Freelance_Writers_Guide_to_Getting_Published.htm).

I cannot emphasize too much that as a student you have access to a large number of people who are most likely published (that's part of what professors get paid to do) who can walk you through this process in your fields of interest.

Comment: Your advice is good in *general*, but since Guy is in/from Lithuania, I'm not sure it's correct in the details.  Since you don't give your location, justkt, I cannot say for sure, but I suspect you're probably not familiar with the Lithuanian academic system.  Neither am I.  (Wish people would give at least their country... *hint* *hint*, *nudge* *nudge* ;-))

Comment: I am studying in the UK, @jae.

Comment: @Guy good to know :-D  Hard to know too, anyway ;-)